# Barcode scanner inserting character by character

Tags: java

Ive been trying a while and cant work out a way to get the text out of a textbox only after the barcode scanner has finished scanning. I am using Swing Framework and Java. My Code works if the text is pasted (Ctrl + V) into the JTextbox but the barcode scanner just does not work as my methods run for every couple of characters of the barcode in turn.

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // warn();
            }

            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // warn();
            }

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                warn();
            }

            public void warn() {
                input = textField.getText();


                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doUpdate);

            }
        });
```

Where input is a variable which I use 
The doUpdate method which gets executed is here

```
final Runnable doUpdate = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(input + " Is being processed");
                textField.setText("");
                System.out.println(input.length());
                lblStatus.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class
                        .getResource("/com/daniel/status2.png")));

                // frame.getContentPane().add(lblStatus2, BorderLayout.EAST);
                if (input.length() <= 4) {
                    lblStatus.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class
                            .getResource("/com/daniel/status3.png")));

                    return;
                }

                // TODO START
                if (!content.containsKey(input)) {
                    content.put(input, "1");
                } else {
                    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(content.get(input));
                    i++;
                    lblStatus.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource(i
                            + ".png")));
                    playSound(i + "");
                    if (i.equals(6)) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    content.put(input, String.valueOf(i));

                }
                System.out.println(content.get(input));
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : content.entrySet()) {
                    properties.put((String) entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }

                try {
                    properties.store(new FileOutputStream(path
                            + "data.properties"), null);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```

All Im asking is how do I run a method with a String from the text box only after the barcode reader has finished

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used a barcode reader, but when I did each scan was a line.  That is, each scan was a sequence of characters terminated by the new line character.  So, you could test the input and only invoke doUpdate when you detect the new line character.  That said, you might need to set a property on the text box to allow the new line character and remove it when detected.

Comment: Yes I thought of doing it, but do all Barcode readers input the new line symbol or an enter after they have finished?

Comment: I cannot say for certain.  All of them that I have seen do.  It seems to be a common protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You need someway to inject a delay between each update of the `DocumentListener` and the time your inspect/use the value from the text field.

A simple solution is to use a Swing `Timer` with a short delay (you can play around with this to find the threashold which is most useful to you).  Each time the `DocumentListener` is notified, you simply reset the timer (start it again), so that it won't trigger until after the delay you specified has occurred, at which time you can read the text from the field.

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Timer updateTimer;
    private JTextField field;
    private JLabel label;

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        updateTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(field.getText());
            }
        });
        updateTimer.setRepeats(false);

        label = new JLabel("...");
        field = new JTextField(14);
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                processUpdate();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                processUpdate();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                processUpdate();
            }

        });

        add(field, gbc);
        add(label, gbc);
    }

    protected void processUpdate() {
        updateTimer.restart();
    }

}
```

You could test this using `Robot`, which can be used to inject key strokes into the event queue with a specified delay, or just run your scanner at it.

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

You should also attach a `ActionListener` to the field and see if the scanner triggers the `ActionListener`, which would be a simpler solution over all

Comment: Yes I thought of doing it, but do all Barcode readers input the new line symbol or an enter after they have finished?

Comment: @djohn316 No idea, that's one of those things you would need to test/investigate further.  AFAIK not all barcode scanners inject key strokes, some have their own APIs or might even use the clipboard :P